Regex a not follwed by b, stop over-capture
I have two possible cases in some XML.
Case 1, incorrect:  <tag att1="text1"/>
Case 2, correct:  <tag att1="text1" att2="text2"/>
So I am trying to find all examples of <tag att1="text1"/> to add attribute 2.
I want to find all my examples of case 1 and add the string for case 2.
<tag att1="(.*?)"/> find both case 1 and case 2
find
<tag att1="(.*?)"(?! att2="(.*?)"/>)
is failing because att1=(.*?) because it still selects att2
<tag att1=(".*?")(?! att2=".*?"/>)
is failing because att1=(.*?) because it still selects att2
How do I prevent my search from finding my case 2 xml?

Like this? <tag att1="[^"]*"(?! att2="[^"]*"/>) https://regex101.com/r/2Dxh2Z/1 or just find <tag att1="[^"]*"/> https://regex101.com/r/atB7Yn/1

<tag att1="([^"]*)"(?!\s+att2="[^"]*"/>) is enough. . matches any char inclusing ". See this answer. For more generic scenarios, see another thread.
